# When i select to check Automatically, the status will have two errors

Tags: ios

Picture is worth a thousand words.

[image]

[image]

Comment: check bundle identifier, team name and in build settings -> set(Code Signing)

Comment: This Not is an answer, just a suggestion. googling the error message, Remember NOT to search using Baidu.com.